# Is default payment method mandatory for PayPal/Braintree integration

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am integrating paypal into my system, and baffled with one question.

Basically PayPal is an aggregator for payment methods, hence you can add multiple cards/accounts for payment procedures. However I am wondering does PayPal move on to next payment methods of the account if the default (chosen by user) one is faild?

Reason why I am asking is that PayPal SDK for vaulting, allows user to choose only one method from popup. (See below image)

If my user chooses only for example `CREDIT UNION 1` and later on it fails to charge money. Will paypal automatically proceed to charge from `Visa` listed bellow?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text in your screenshot explains what happens:

> [image]

The selected funding source will be used. If it can't be used, another funding source will be used. If none can be used, the transaction will fail.

Comment: Well, should be careful!
Thanks a lot)

Comment: I see you have solid experience with PayPal, can I ask you additional help in regards of architecture/design of the PayPal integration for recurring payments?

Comment: Yes, I suppose. You can also raise a new question here if it's relevant to StackOverflow